# MS Access equivalent for using dense_rank in select

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, floor, dense-rank

In MS Access, I have a table with 2 million account records/rows with various columns of data. I wish to apply a sequence number to every account record. (i.e.- 1 for the first account record ABC111, 2 for the second account record DEF222..., etc.)

Then, I would like to assign a batch number sequence for every **5 distinct account number**. (i.e - record 1 with account number ABC111 being associated with batch number 101, record 2 with account number DEF222 being associated with batch number of 101)

This is how I would do it with a sql server query:

```
select distinct(p.accountnumber),FLOOR(((50 + dense_rank() over(order by        
p.accountnumber)) - 1)/5) + 100 As BATCH from 
db2inst1.account_table p
```

Raw Data:

```
AccountNumber    
ABC111           
DEF222           
GHI333           
JKL444           
MNO555           
PQR666           
STU777
```

Resulting Data:

```
RecordNumber    AccountNumber     BatchNumber
1               ABC111            101
2               DEF222            101
3               GHI333            101
4               JKL444            101 
5               MNO555            101 
6               PQR666            102 
7               STU777            102
```

I tried to make a query that uses SELECT as well as DENSE_RANK but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would probably work.

I'd first create a temporary table to hold the distinct account numbers, then I'd do an update query to assign the ranking.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpAccountRank
    (AccountNumber TEXT(10)
        CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY,
    AccountRank INTEGER NULL);
```

Then I'd use this table to generate the account ranking.

```
DELETE FROM tmpAccountRank;
INSERT INTO tmpAccountRank(AccountNumber)
SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber FROM db2inst1.account_table;
UPDATE tmpAccountRank
SET AccountRank =
    DCOUNT('AccountNumber', 'tmpAccountRank',
        'AccountNumber < ''' + AccountNumber + '''') \ 5 + 101
```

I use DCOUNT and integer division (\ 5) to generate the ranking. This probably will have terrible performance but I think it's the way you would do it in MS Access.

<s>If you want to skip the temp table, you can do it all in a nested subquery, but I don't think it's a great practice to do too much in a single query, especially in MS Access.</s>

<s>SELECT AccountNumber,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber
        FROM db2inst1.account_table
        WHERE AccountNumber < t.AccountNumber) q)) \ 5 + 101
FROM db2inst1.account_table t</s>

Actually, this won't work in MS Access; apparently you can't reference tables outside of multiple levels of nesting in a subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, I'm not too worried about performance, as I am using MS access to normalize large flat file data that I would then export.

Comment: Tmdean, what values would t.AccountNumber have? I'm not quite sure what is being accomplished with your last query. Do you mind giving a further breakdown please?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't actually test the last query, and it looks like Access doesn't support referencing a table from within a nested subquery. I think we're stuck with the temp table method.

Comment: I used your temp table method and was able to successfully assign the batch numbers.Thanks! Now I must use a type of vlookup function to add the batch number field from the temp table to my original table. Any ideas on how I can accomplish that with a query?

Comment: This would be a very straightforward update query in Access; you should be able to figure it out by reading up on how to make Access queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `dense_rank()` with a correlated subquery.  The logic is:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(distinct a2.accountnumber)
        from db2inst1.account_table as a2
        where a2.accountnumber <= a.accountnumber
       ) as dense_rank
from db2inst1.account_table as a;
```

Then, you can use this for getting the batch number.  Unfortunately, I don't follow the logic in your question (`dense_rank()` produces a number but your batch number is not numeric).  However, this should answer your question.

EDIT:

Oh, that's right.  In MS Access you need nested subqueries:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(*)
        from (select distinct a2.accountnumber
              from db2inst1.account_table as a2
             )  as a2
        where a2.accountnumber <= a.accountnumber
       ) as dense_rank
from db2inst1.account_table as a;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! To give more clarity, essentially, I was trying to implement this excel function as a sql server query: =ROUNDDOWN((ROW()+$G$7-1)/$G$7,0)+$G$8 ) where the value in $G$7 is 5 and the value in $G$8 is 100. Which I successfully did with the above sql server query: select distinct(p.accountnumber),FLOOR(((50 + dense_rank() over(order by p.accountnumber)) - 1)/5) + 100 As BATCH from db2inst1.account_table p But now I'm trying to implement this as a MS Access Query.

Comment: MS Access doesn't have COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

Comment: Gordon, is there is a work around for what Tmdean noted in his last comment?

Comment: @Thinkmad . . . Of course.  It is a pretty easy work-around.